# Xcode compiler - swiftc failed with exit code 1

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, compiler-errors

I have the following code:

```
protocol DataSourceItem { }

protocol TableDataSourceItem : DataSourceItem { }



class DataSource<T : DataSourceItem> { }

class TableDataSource<T : TableDataSourceItem>: DataSource<T> { }



class DataSourceBuilder<T : TableDataSourceItem, U : TableDataSource<T>> { }

class TableDataSourceBuilder<T : TableDataSourceItem, U : TableDataSource<T>> : DataSourceBuilder<T, U> { }



enum MyItem: TableDataSourceItem { }

class MyBuilder : TableDataSourceBuilder<MyItem, TableDataSource<MyItem>> { }

let builder = MyBuilder()
```

But Xcode doesn't compile, failing with the error:

> Command /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/swiftc failed with exit code 1

I've tried doing the usual cleaning, rebooting, etc but with no luck.

Note, the above code is the exact code I'm trying to compile in a new single view project with nothing else added to it.

When commenting out lines to find the culprit, the code works if I comment out the following:

```
class TableDataSourceBuilder<T : TableDataSourceItem, U : TableDataSource<T>> : DataSourceBuilder<T, U> { }



enum MyItem: TableDataSourceItem { }

class MyBuilder : TableDataSourceBuilder<MyItem, TableDataSource<MyItem>> { }

let builder = MyBuilder()
```

Specifically, the line:

```
class TableDataSourceBuilder<T : TableDataSourceItem, U : TableDataSource<T>> : DataSourceBuilder<T, U> { }
```

I'm assuming it's do to with `TableDataSource<T>`.

I can't see any syntax errors here though.

Comment: Causes LLVM error with Swift 3.0.2, which I think is a compiler bug.

Comment: @kennytm Thanks for the reply. Do you know if this bug has been reported?

Comment: FYI, just posted this as a bug in Swift: https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-3884